# Notation problem for Gaussian Distribution. Vertical Bar

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, normal-distribution, machine-learning

In ["Gaussian Process Latent Variable Models forVisualisation of High Dimensional Data" by Lawrence](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2540-gaussian-process-latent-variable-models-for-visualisation-of-high-dimensional-data.pdf) I stepped over the following definitions of Gaussian Distributions:

$p(x) = N(x|0,I)$

$p(y|x,W,\beta) = N(y|Wx,\beta^{-1}I)$

[$\rightarrow$ Full definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vvKN.png)

What is the meaning of the vertical Bar in $N(\cdot|\cdot,\cdot)$? And what are the actuall mean $\mu$ of the distrubutions?

Comment: I do agree that this notation is horrible, but i think the author means that $x$ is an outcome of a $N(0,I)$ distribution and that the conditional distribution $Y| X=x$ is a $N(Wx,\beta^{-1}I)$ distribution. The expected value of $x$ is $0$, the expected value of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $Wx$. The expected value of $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}[WX] = W\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$. 
Edit: My interpretation only makes sense if $W$ and $\beta$ are constant matrices/vectors, which is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, $f(x|a, b)$ means you should consider $f$ as a function of $x$, and think of $a$ and $b$ as the parameters of the function. Here, $N(x|0,I)$ means probability density of $x$ according to the normal distribution with mean $0$ (vector zero) and variance $I$. You can think of mean and the variance as the parameters of the probability density function. Also, the conditional probability density of $y$ is determined by a normal distribution with mean $Wx$ and variance $\beta^{-1} I$.

Comment: So I can understand $N(a|b,c)$ as something like $N_a(b,c)$?

Comment: No, rather $N_{b,c}(a)$